# How to know if my Jsoup element is being properly selected

Tags: android, image, parsing, jsoup, element

I am trying to debug an issue I am having. I am using the following code to try to get the link to an image off of a page.

```
private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    String urls = args[0];
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(urls).ignoreContentType(true).get();
        image = doc.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]").last();
        theurlstring = "test " + image.attr("src"); // I put test here to make sure it is being executed
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return urls;
}
}
```

I am usually getting an error from any way I am trying to get the link from the Element "image." It says

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.jsoup.nodes.Element.attr(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

So with that error, I am now thinking that image is not getting selected properly. Does anyone see anything that looks wrong? Or how could I pinpoint the problem better?

Comment: Is this resolved? Please post a follow up question in the comments bellow otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not working, see http://try.jsoup.org/~I4Y0POaloHUtrNTMJO7IAiAUIRY

You could use:

```
image = doc.select("img[src$=.png],img[src$=.gif],img[src$=.jpg],img[src$=.jpeg]").last();
```

Not as compact, but at least selecting the images (see http://try.jsoup.org/~kjnlfvCzrxiqaGQqwcszLZswSNg).

If the error persists, use try.jsoup.org with your source url to verify, that the expected output is rendered in the received html, to rule out issues with javascript generated content.